# Android Marshmallow Permission Error

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

i am adding certain permissions to my app to allow access to camera for example and everything is working fine. but when i minimize the app and disable the permission then open the app, the app crashes without asking me to re-enable the permission(until i close the app and then open it). how can i fix this error so that the app dont crash and ask again for permission or safe restart to ask for permissions.

here is my code

in the main activity:

onCreate:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    GlobalVariables.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }


@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode)
        {

            case GlobalVariables.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA:
            {
                if (grantResults.length <= 0
                        || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    globalVariables.ShowOKAlert("Error","Please Accept All Requested Permissions or the app wont function properly",this,false);
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

the activity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback

Comment: Note that when you disable the permission in Settings, your app's process is terminated.

Comment: thank you @CommonsWare, i think due to this i am having some errors in the SQLITE database

Comment: Try this it may be help you:-http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1):

step 1:

```
 String[] permissions = new String[]{ 
    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
 };
```

Step 2:-

```
private boolean checkPermissions() {
    int result;
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String p : permissions) {
        result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, p);
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
             listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
        }
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), 100);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Step 3:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // do something
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking that permission in `onCreate`. When you minimize and maximize the app again that method is not called.

Maybe you should check that permission in the extact point where you need it, or at least in `onResume` which surely is called again when you re-open your app.

Calling it in `onResume` ensure the app continues to work also if the user disables the permission in another window with the screen splitted (Android N feature).

Comment: ok thanks will try that. but the error is appearing as soon as i maximize the app...i.e. i didnt actualy launch the camera yet and was still in the main activity

Comment: may you post the stack trace?

Comment: in the stack trace, the error i am getting when disabling any permission i have (camera, location, storage) is  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.isOpen()' on a null object reference which doesnt make sense

Comment: Ok, it seems unrelated to the permissions' management. Does it is thrown only if you disable the permission? Or also if you just minimize and maximize the app?

Comment: you should post something more... at least the code with the exact row where the app crashes

Comment: ok thanks man i will try and post something more useful once i find more info.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to achieve this to use direct static method of `ActivityCompat`

```
public static void requestPermissions(final @NonNull Activity activity,
            final @NonNull String[] permissions, final int requestCode)
```

Here you can see what parameters you have required for this

`-- Activity Instance`

`-- String array of permissions`

`-- a user defined request code`

**Usage**

Define global variables

```
//Run-time permissions for MarshMallow +
    public final String[] PERMISSION_ALL = {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };
    //validateRequestPermissionsRequestCode requires requestCode to be of 8 bits, i.e. range: 0-255.
    public final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
```

Finally in your activity `oncreate()` method you can call static function mentioned above

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    //your code here

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //do other code work

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSION_ALL, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        //do other code work
    }

    //your code here
}
```

And you are done....

For more Info [Click here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/training/permissions/requesting.html) about Android Permissions At Run Time